# Saving html form in database in xml format

Tags: javascript, php

Language = html/js - php server side

Acutally i save a form in datase in xml so it's look lik

```
<item>
   <textarea>value of text area</textarea>
</item>
```

but the value of textarea look more like this : <p><strong>sdfasdf</strong></p>

so when i receive it in js i can't decode.

What is the bset way to save it in xml or does xml is a bas choice?

thanks

Comment: you should look into saving it as JSON instead if you plan to save strings with html tags inside.